# Can I get some tips With My Inventory system for my game. I want to use an object in my inventory with another object (like a Key to a Door)

Tags: actionscript-3

This is my Main Class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;


public class InventoryDemo extends MovieClip {
    var inventory:Inventory;

    public function InventoryDemo() {

    }
    public function initialiseInventory():void
    {
        inventory = new Inventory(this);
        inventory.makeInventoryItems([d1,d2]);
    }
}
```

}

I used a sprite indicator to show that the items are inside the inventory.
And this is my child class:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Inventory
{
    var itemsInInventory:Array;
    var inventorySprite:Sprite;

    public function Inventory(parentMC:MovieClip)
    {
        itemsInInventory = new Array  ;
        inventorySprite = new Sprite  ;
        inventorySprite.x = 50;
        inventorySprite.y = 360;
        parentMC.addChild(inventorySprite);

    }
    function makeInventoryItems(arrayOfItems:Array)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++)
        {
            arrayOfItems[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getItem);
            arrayOfItems[i].buttonMode = true;
        }
    }

    function getItem(e:Event)
    {
        var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
        itemsInInventory.push(item);
        inventorySprite.addChild(item);
        item.x = itemsInInventory.length - 1 * 40;
        item.y = 0;
        item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getItem);
        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,useItem);
    }

    function useItem(e:Event)
    {
        var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
        trace(("Use Item:" + item.name));
    }
 }
```

}

Currently i can only click and trace the output, I was wondering how i can drag the sprite and use it to another object...like a key to unlock a door. Big thanks, btw im new in as3 and im trying to learn from stack overflow.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to drag d1 to a movie clip called door in order to move to the next keyframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,useItem);

var drag:Boolean;

function useItem(e:Event)
{
    var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
    trace(("Use Item:" + item.name));
    if(drag == false)
    {
        item.startDrag();
        drag = true;
    }else{
        item.stopDrag();
        drag = false;
        findAction(e);
    }
}

function findAction(e)
{
    // Check the position of the key relative to the door.
}
```

Haven't really checked it but it'd probably work if you did something similar.

Comment: can i put in the function a ".hitTestObject"... like: if d1.hitTestObject(door_mc)) for the function findAction(e)

Comment: Yea, I guess a hit test would work there. Personally I'd check the x/y positions instead but whichever works for you. Also you can probably define d1 as e.currentTarget since the code passes it forward to findAction, so you'll be able to use this code for other stuff as well.

Comment: e.currentTarget? i dont understand, sorry im quite new to as3.

Comment: Oh ignore that, I misread that part of your code anyway. Yea, use a hit test on d1 in the function findAction.

Comment: Just remembered, you need to change the drag variable on each click, I've added two lines to my code above.

Comment: im having "Access of undefined property d1." I got this 3 times, for both the .startDrag in the "if and else"                             I tried adding "if (d1.hitTestObject(dust))", dust being another movie clip in my frame.

Comment: Try changing d1 to e.target

Comment: Also, put the hitTest under the findAction function.

Comment: I did put the hitTest inside findAction...will changing the e.target only let me pick d1? what if i have three times in the inventory

Comment: e.target will be whatever item is being dragged.

Comment: I still dont get it...could you give an example please?

Comment: I updated my answer, so try now. If it still doesn't work, edit your question with an updated version of your code and any questions/errors so I can take a better look at where you're at.

Comment: Hi @Neguido, ok thx for the help, i got my iteam to work now, question...how do i check the item's position relative to the door once i start dragging??? will a simple hit test work??

Comment: Yea it will, and no problem :).

Comment: Thx alot, can I ask one last question? How can I remove the item from the inventory once i have used it? like the key should disappear onced its used...

Comment: I found this code online but i dont know where to place it..........public function useItem(e:MouseEvent)
{
       var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
      inventorySprite.removeChild(item);
      itemsInInventory.splice(itemsInInventory.indexOf(item), 1);
      item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useItem);
      sortInventory();
}
public function sortInventory()
{
       for (var i:int = 0; i < itemsInInventory.length; i++)
      {
            itemsInInventory[i].x = i * 40;
      }
}

Comment: Ok, your inventory is in an Array so after the item has been used you're gonna wanna call another function such as 'removeItem'. Pass the e variable so the function can find the item in the Array, then remove it!